# При вставки неразрывного проблема &nbsp; на 12 айфоне выдает странные символы

Tags: html

При вставки неразрывного проблема & nbsp на 12 айфоне выдает такие символы, предположу, что это из-за & nbsp. Из-за чего это появляется и как это можно решить? На андроидах, на пк и на 11 айфоне все правильно отображается. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<p class="promo__wrap__content__subtitle">Наши специалисты оказывают профессиональные услуги в&nbsp;области digital и&nbsp;cloud трансформации</p>
```

Comment: не использовать айфон  

Comment: предъявите код, который это вызывает

Comment: <p class="promo__wrap__content__subtitle">Наши специалисты оказывают профессиональные услуги в&nbsp;области digital и&nbsp;cloud трансформации</p>

Comment: Про подобный глюк писали. Ищите в google

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253913015